# 1970's book where near-immortal people live in domes and a machine brings them back when they die

Tags: story-identification, books

I believe it's by a woman author. It's her most famous book.

It depicted a world far in the future, where humans live in domes and are more or less immortal. Every time they die they return to a machine that tries to teach them and then return them to life in whatever form they prefer.

The narrator starts off as a woman and becomes a man later in the book and it deals somewhat with the trauma of that. She goes camping in a small dome and her dog gets killed. Wealthy people are fitted with wings.

Comment: Too much of a stretch to write an answer but reminiscent in some ways of John Varley's *Eight Worlds* stories.

Comment: Based on 'near-immortal people', 'live in domes' and 'a machine brings them back when they die', I was thinking of Bionicle for a split second...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is possibly the duology by Tanith Lee consisting of *Don't Bite the Sun* and *Drinking Sapphire Wine*. The nameless protagonist is a misfit and is trying to find fulfillment in their life - at their age they're supposed to be all about hedonism - and is constantly suiciding and getting new bodies. The domes are named - I only remember Four BEE and Four BAA.

Comment: THATS IT!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: The remaining dome is Four BOO.

Comment: However, it is not Tanith Lee's most famous book. If you liked _Don't Bite the Sun_ and _Drinking Sapphire Wine_ (which have been published both separately and under a single set of covers), you will probably also like _The Silver Metal Lover_.

Comment: The reviewer [James Davis Nicoll](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com) has a review series ["A Year of Tanith Lee"](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/reviews/project/a-year-of-tanith-lee) focusing on this writer, with 61 reviews in the category.

Answer (score 0):

Near immortal people + machine bringing back.

Arthur C. Clark wrote two books, or rather wrote one, then rewrote it.  The original was "Against the Fall of Night."  The second was "The City and the Stars"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_and_the_Stars

Both are worth reading.

Comment: Once a story id question has an accepted answer, it's rather pointless to post a different one.

Comment: Not necessarily. Other people searching for books that match the question's criteria might might their answer in this later, unaccepted, answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Doesn't what you're suggesting make every ID question a list question? "We've got the answer, but what other stories are there with one or more of these elements?" Not that it bothers me any, I'm not the one who passed the rule against list questions.

Comment: @user14111: I can see that perspective, but to me, there's the fundamental difference between asking for the list, and people providing correct answers which aren't the correct answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots these string of 'close but no cigar' answers to previously answered id questions look like forum posts to me. Not SE answer posts. I am not sure what a 'correct answer that is not the correct answer' means. These answers are knowingly wrong answers by definition. If the work had not already been id'd this would be a reasonable guess.

Comment: Hmm... I hope you don't mind, but I went ahead and wrote up a Meta question at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13233/story-id-answers-after-an-accepted-one-are-they-useful

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I wrote an answer at the oldest of the three duplicate meta  questions on this topic. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13235/28516